# Using #states on an inline paragraph form

Tags: 9

I have a field on a custom content type which is a reference to a paragraph type, using the Paragraph (EXPERIMENTAL) widget. I'm trying to modify that widget to show and hide a field based on another field on the paragraph. Here is my widget alter code:

```
$field = 'field_supporter_form_fields';
$id_field = 'field_primary_custom';
$delta = $element['#delta'];
$id = sprintf('select[name="%s[%d][subform][%s]"]', $field, $delta, $id_field);
$element['subform']['field_field_type']['widget']['#states'] = [ 
  'visible' => [
    $id => ['value' => 'custom'],
  ],
];
$element['subform']['field_field_type']['widget']['#title'] = 'Blah!';
```

I know that I'm targeting the correct widget because I see the field title change to "Blah!", but the visibility of the field doesn't change.

Here's what the relevant part of the $element array looks like after the alter:

```
[#parents] => Array
    (
        [0] => field_supporter_form_fields
        [1] => 0
        [2] => subform
        [3] => field_field_type
    )

[#states] => Array
    (
        [visible] => Array
            (
                [select[name="field_supporter_form_fields[0][subform][field_primary_custom]"]] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => custom
                    )

            )

    )
```

The dependant field `field_primary_custom` is a pair of radio buttons with values of either primary or custom. The name of the element on the page is `field_supporter_form_fields[0][subform][field_primary_custom]` which matches what I have in my identifier.

Why isn't the visibility changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use input instead of select. Not entirely sure why, but it works!